# Find sum of tuples by eliminating null values

Tags: mysql, select

Say,i've an table named x with column named yyy with values 1,2,3,NULL

To eliminate null values,i can write a query SELECT yyy FROM x WHERE yyy IS NOT NULL.

Now ,how do i find sum for the above result.In general to find sum alone for yyy,i can write a query SELECT SUM(yyy) FROM x.

To do above,i know that i should write a sub query,i tried this but did not work

SELECT SUM(SELECT yyy FROM x WHERE yyy IS NOT NULL) FROM x but this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(yyy,0)) FROM x
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Just write:

```
SELECT SUM(yyy) FROM x
```

Quoting mysql docs: [Unless otherwise stated, group functions ignore NULL values.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)